# NPM detect pre-release dependency in package.json/package-lock.json?

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

Is there a way to detect pre-release dependencies in package.json or package-lock.json?

My context is I would like to create a git "TAG" to indicate release candidates of my code. 
I would like to make sure all my in-house developed modules do not have dependencies on any pre-release modules.

I would like to detect presence of a pre-release dependencies( "^1.0.3-NIGHTLY") in my package.json as below example:

```
    "@mydomain/client-mgr-service": "^1.0.3-NIGHTLY",  <= I would like to be able to detect this line if there is a NPM feature out-of-box
    "@types/country-data": "0.0.0",
    "amazon-cognito-identity-js": "^3.0.12",
```

Thanks in advance for any helps given~

Comment: There is nothing built-in to npm to achieve this AFAIK. You could utilize a node.js script to parse _package.json_ or _package-lock.json_, i.e. `JSON.parse(...)`, and detect the presence of a pre-release. Alternatively if you want to check the projects complete dependency tree for a  pre-release you could (from a node.js script)  shell out the [`npm ls -json`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls.html) command from within your project directory and then `JSON.parse(...)` the results to detect the presence of a pre-release.

Comment: Thanks @RobC.  I figure what I am trying to acheive is quite ordinary for CICD practice. Just wondering how do ppl usually avoid pre-release dependency in their project? OR can you share your solution, I am open to any suggestions, no necessarily on package.json/package-lock.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple solution I used to detect if there is any pre-release dependencies in my package.json. The idea is to check if there is a "-" right after semver's x.y.z numbers.

```
grep -P "([0-9]\d*)\.([0-9]\d*)\.([0-9]\d*)-" package.json
```